# Cannot backup table in postgreSQL using pgAdmin 4

Tags: pgadmin, pgadmin-4

I'm trying to backup my postgreSQL 9.6 database using pgAdmin 4. First, when I tried to use backup, it failed saying that I have to set the binary path on my pgAdmin preferences. It maybe worth noting that I have recently changed the password of user `postgres` to `postgres`.

I googled this issue and found an answer (not sure if it's correct though), I set the value of `PostgreSQL Binay Path` to  `/usr/lib/postgresql`.

However now when I try to back up a table, I get the following error:

[image: Error snapshot]

I keep the defaults except for these values:

```
Only schema: YES
Use Column Insert: YES
Use Insert Commands: YES
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to provide a path where binaries from PostgreSQL-9.6 are present.

```
root@x0x:/opt/PostgreSQL/9.6/bin# pwd
/opt/PostgreSQL/9.6/bin

root@x0x:/opt/PostgreSQL/9.6/bin# ls
clusterdb   droplang  pg_archivecleanup  pg_ctl      pg_recvlogical  pg_test_fsync   pltcl_listmod  psql.bin
createdb    dropuser  pg_basebackup  pg_dump     pg_resetxlog    pg_test_timing  pltcl_loadmod  reindexdb
createlang  ecpg      pgbench        pg_dumpall  pg_restore  pg_upgrade  postgres   vacuumdb
createuser  initdb    pg_config      pg_isready  pg_rewind   pg_xlogdump     postmaster vacuumlo
dropdb      oid2name  pg_controldata     pg_receivexlog  pg_standby  pltcl_delmod    psql
```

Check the sample path in screenshot which is working for me, so according to your postgres installation set proper path in preference and you are good to go, make sure not to add any unwanted whitespace before or after path.

[image]

Comment: I've checked my `/opt/` folder, but it doesn't contain a folder named `PostgresSQL`

Comment: You have to set the path as per your postgres installation/configuration, I just gave the reference of mine.

Comment: Thanks a lot, mine was: `/usr/bin`. Backup works fine now.

Answer (score 1):

Copy paste bin folder of Postgresql version: C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\16\bin and add it in PgAdmin 4 -> Preferences -> Path: Binary paths -> EDB & PostgreSQL Binary Path latest version